# Why is $M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$ a ring without unity?

Tags: ring-theory

I can understand that The set $M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$ of $2 \times 2$
matrices with even integer entries is an infinite non commutative ring. But why It doesn't have any unity? I think $I(2\times2)$ is a unity for this ring. 
Where is my misunderstanding in subject of $I(2\times2)$ being a unity?

Comment: Ok guys I forget that elements in I(2X2) are in 2Z. thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I(2\times 2)=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]\not\in M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$ since $M_2(2\mathbb{Z})$ has only even integers as its entries. It can be shown using an arbitrary matrix $B$ that $I(2\times 2)$ is the only possible unity in $M_2(2\mathbb{Z}),$ but since it is not an element of $M_2(2\mathbb{Z}),$ there is no unity. There are other rings without a unity, such as $2\mathbb{Z},$ the set of even integers.

Btw, the notation $2\mathbb{Z}$ is equivalent to the ideal $\langle 2\rangle := \{2x : x\in\mathbb{Z}\},$ if you didn't know.

Comment: Well... I guess you've replaced a faulty argument with a statement that what you want can be proven, so it's an improvement. But better yet would be giving the reason :) I guess the part hidden in "it can be shown" isn't too hard, and you could justify leaving it as an exercise...

Comment: I don't understand your question. Invertible where? Of course it has to be invertible in the ring in which it is an identity, but it doesn't have to be in the containing ring.  Either way I don't understand its relevance.

Comment: If you are referring to Chris's answer, I won't comment about its correctness, all I meant is that he is *giving a reason.* When I reread it I saw that it was not quite the reason I thought he was going to give, so I should not have said "proves it" earlier.  Since the first three comments are now obsolete, i'll delete them...

Comment: "It can be shown" cannot easily be shown.

Answer (score 1):

The $2\times 2$ identity has entries $1,0,0,1$. Are all of those are even numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix ring had an identity element $I,$ then the square of its determinant would have to be $1$ (or $0$), since $I^2=I.$ The determinant cannot be $0$ since $I$ is invertible (or, non-singular, if you prefer). But the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix over $2\mathbb{Z}$ is even ($ad-bc$ is a difference of a product of even numbers). So, you cannot have an identity element in this ring.

Comment: You might also want to ponder the observation that $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring without $1.$

Comment: Why must the identity element be invertible?

Comment: By definition, if $e$ is an identity element in a ring, then $er=re=r$ for all $r$ in the ring, in particular, $ee=e.$ So, $e$ is its own inverse with respect to the ring multiplication.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Of course an identity is invertible in its own ring, but when you say "nonsingular" you are referring to units of the full matrix ring. It can very well be that the identity of a ring inside a ring isn't invertible in the whole ring.  So, more reasoning is necessary to explain why the case of $0$ is eliminated.

Comment: You could patch it this way: suppose $I$ is nonsingular in $M_2(\mathbb Q)$. Then there is a nonzero column vector $v\in \mathbb Q^2$ such that $Iv=0$.  Then it is easy to reason that you can scale $v$ to have entries in $2\mathbb Z$. Then the matrix $B$ with both columns equal to $v$ is a nonzero matrix such that $IB=0$, which contradicts the role of $I$ as the identity.  Thus the determinant has to be $1$, which is an absurdity since $\det(I)\in 2\mathbb Z$, as you said.

Comment: @rschwieb. -My bad on that. I should have caught it. Any ring $R$ with $1$ embeds  in $M_2(R)$ as the matrices with some $r \in R$ in the upper left hand entry and $0$ elsewhere. When $r=1$ the resulting matrix serves as identity in the image of $R$ but not in the full matrix ring. This is such a basic standard example. In any event, this commentary is for the OP (who may or may not ever read it), not for you. Thanks for drawing my attention to this, and for the patch.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone pointed out right away, your candidate is not an element of your ring.

Here is a slightly different way to prove that $M_2(2\mathbb Z)$ can't have an identity.

Notice that because your entries are always sums of products of things in $2\mathbb Z$, you're always accumulating powers of two.

In particular,

1. if $I$ is a nonzero element such that $I^2=I$ (this must hold for an identity!), then $I\in M_2(4\mathbb Z)$.
2. Then $IA\in M_2(8\mathbb Z)$ for any matrix $A\in M_2(2\mathbb Z)$.
3. But you know that you can pick $A\in M_2(2\mathbb Z)\setminus M_2(8\mathbb Z)$.
4. This contradicts the observation that $A=AI\in M_2(8\mathbb Z)$.

---

Here is another argument reminiscent of Chris Leary's approach. Suppose $E$ is the identity of $M_2(2\mathbb Z)$.

Then the adjugate matrix $\mathrm{adj}(E)\in M_2(2\mathbb Z)$ also, and satisfies $E\mathrm{adj}(E)=det(E)I_2\in M_2(2\mathbb Z)$. In particular, $\det(E)$ is an even number.  Also observe that both $E$ and $\mathrm{adj}(E)$ are both nonzero.

Since $E^2=E$, we have $\det(E)=\det(E)^2$, and the only two integers that satisfy $x^2=x$ are $0$ and $1$, and $1$ is obviously not even.

So $\det(E)=0$: but then $\mathrm{adj}(E)=E\mathrm{adj}(E)=0$, contradicting the earlier observation that $\mathrm{adj}(E)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $I(2\times2)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then $I(2\times2)\notin M_2(2\mathbb Z)$ since $1$ is odd.